Understanding Proof of Proposition 2.2.5 from Measure Theory by Donald Cohn
Overview
I am self-studying Donald Cohn's Measury Theory. I have some questions about his proof of Proposition 2.2.5, and I would like to confirm if my attempt to understand his proof is correct.
Here is the statement of the proposition with the proof:

Proposition 2.2.5$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$ be the completion of $\mathscr{A}$ under $\mu$. Then a function $f:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable if and only if there are $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions $f_0,f_1:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ such that
\begin{align}
    f_0\leq f\leq f_1\ \textit{holds everywhere on $X$}\tag1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    f_0=f_1\ \textit{holds $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$.}\tag2
\end{align}


Proof$\quad$ First suppose that there exist $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ that satisfy (1) and (2). Then $f_0$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable and $f=f_0$ holds $\overline{\mu}$-almost everywhere. Hence, Proposition 2.2.2 applied to the space $(X,\mathscr{A}_{\mu},\overline{\mu})$, implies that $f$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable.
Now suppose that $f:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable. If $f$ is simple and $[0,+\infty)$-valued, say attaining values $a_1,\dots,a_k$ on the sets $A_1,\dots,A_k$, then there are sets $B_1,\dots,B_k$ and $C_1,\dots,C_k$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfy $C_i\subseteq A_i\subseteq B_i$ and $\mu(B_i-C_i)=0$ for each $i$. The functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ defined by $f_0=\sum_ia_i\chi_{C_i}$ and $f_1=\sum_ia_i\chi_{B_i}$ then satisfy (1) and (2).
We can deal with the case where $f$ is simple and real-valued by applying the preceding argument to the positive and negative parts of $f$.
Finally, let $f:X\to[-\infty,+\infty]$ be an arbitrary $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable function, and choose a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of simple $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)$ holds at each $x$ in $X$. If for each $n$, we choose $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions $g_{0,n}$ and $g_{1,n}$ such that
\begin{align*}
    g_{0,n}\leq g_n\leq g_{1,n}\ \text{holds everywhere on $X$}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    g_{0,n}=g_{1,n}\ \text{holds $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$,}
\end{align*}
then the required functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ can be constructed by letting $f_0$ be $\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}$ and $f_1$ be $\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}$.

My Questions

In the first paragraph of the proof, it asserts that $f_0$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable and $f=f_0$ holds $\overline{\mu}$-almost everywhere. But why?

In the second paragraph of the proof, it says that "$f$ ... attaining values $a_1,\dots,a_k$ on the sets $A_1,\dots,A_k$. My question is why can we assume that the set of possible values attained by $f$ is finite?

Still in the second paragrph, why do $f_0=\sum_ia_i\chi_{C_i}$ and $f_1=\sum_ia_i\chi_{B_i}$ satisfy (1) and (2)?

The existence of $g_{0,n}$ and $g_{1,n}$ for each $n$?

In the last paragraph, why do $f_0=\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}$ and $f_1=\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}$ satisfy (1) and (2)?


My Attempts
Here are my attempts so far:

First suppose that there exist $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions $f_0$ and $f_1$ that satisfy (1) and (2). The measurability of $f_0$ implies that $\{x\in X:f_0(x)\leq t\}\in\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$. It follows that $f_0$ is $\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$-measurable.
Since $f_0=f_1$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$, we have $\{x\in X:f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)\}$ is $\mu$-negligible. So let $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\{x\in X:f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)\}\subseteq A$, and $\mu(A)=0$. Since $f_0(x)\leq f(x)\leq f_1(x)$ for all $x\in X$, it follows that $\{x\in X:f(x)\neq f_0(x)\} \subseteq \{x\in X:f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)\}$. Therefore, the set $A$ satisfies $A\in\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{A}_{\mu}$, $\{x\in X:f(x)\neq f_0(x)\}\subseteq A$, and $\overline{\mu}(A)=\mu(A)=0$, so that the set $\{x\in X:f(x)\neq f_0(x)\}$ is $\overline{\mu}$-negligible and $f=f_0$ holds $\overline{\mu}$-almost everywhere.

I still don't know why. I think the set of possible values may not even be countable.

If $x\in A_i$, then $f(x)=a_i$. Also, $x\in A_i\subseteq B_i$ implies that $\chi_{B_i}(x)=1$, so that $f_1(x)\geq a_i$. Now,
\begin{align*}
\chi_{C_i}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\ \text{if $x \in C_i$}\\
0\ \text{if $x \in A_i-C_i$}
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Moreover if $x \in A_i-C_i$ then $x \notin C_j$ for $j\neq i$, because otherwise if $x\in C_j\subseteq A_j$ it would contradicts $A_i\bigcap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Therefore, $f_0(x)\leq a_i$. Thus, $f_0(x)\leq f(x)\leq f_1(x)$ for all $x\in X$.
We now show that $f_0=f_1$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$. Consider the set $\bigcup_i(B_i-C_i)$. Since each $B_i$ and $C_i$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, we have $\bigcup_i(B_i-C_i)\in\mathscr{A}$. Since $\mu(B_i-C_i)=0$ for each $i$, the countable additivity of $\mu$ implies that $\mu\left(\bigcup_i(B_i-C_i)\right)=0$. Now suppose $f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)$ for some $x$. If $x$ is in some $C_i$, then $x\in A_i\subseteq B_i$ and $x\notin A_j$ for $j\neq i$ and so $x\notin B_j$ for $j\neq i$. Then $f_0(x) = a_i = f_1(x)$, a contradiction. Therefore, $x$ is not in any $C_i$. But $x$ must be in some $B_i$. Thus, $x\in\bigcup_i(B_i-C_i)$, and so $\{x\in X:f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)\}\subseteq\bigcup_i(B_i-C_i)$. Hence, $\{x\in X:f_0(x)\neq f_1(x)\}$ is $\mu$-negligible and $f_0=f_1$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$.

The third paragraph in the original proof guarantees the existence of such $g_{0,n}$ and $g_{1,n}$ for each $n$.

To show $f_0(x)\leq f(x)\leq f_1(x)$ for all $x\in X$, note that
\begin{align*}
f_0(x) &= \limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}(x)\\
&=\inf_k\sup_{n\geq k}g_{0,n}(x)\\
&\leq\inf_k\sup_{n\geq k}g_{n}(x)\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)\\
&= f(x)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty}g_n(x)\\
&= \sup_k\inf_{n\geq K}g_n(x)\\
&\leq \sup_k\inf_{n\geq k}g_{1,n}(x)\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}(x)\\
&= f_1(x),
\end{align*}
and we are done.
We now prove $f_0=f_1$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. Suppose that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}(x)\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}(x)$; that is, suppose that
\begin{align*}
\inf_k\sup_{n\geq k}g_{0,n}(x)\neq\sup_k\inf_{n\geq k}g_{1,n}(x).\tag3
\end{align*}
Then $g_{0,n}\neq g_{1,n}$ for some $n$. For otherwise, if $g_{0,n} = g_{1,n}$, we would have equality in (3). Therefore, $\{x\in X:\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}(x)\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}(x)\}\subseteq\{x\in X:g_{0,n}\neq g_{1,n}\}$. Since $g_{0,n}=g_{1,n}$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere, it follows that $\{x\in X:g_{0,n}\neq g_{1,n}\}$ is $\mu$-negligible; that is, there exists an $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\{x\in X:g_{0,n}\neq g_{1,n}\}\in\mathscr{A}$, and $\mu(A)=0$. Hence, there exists an $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\{x\in X:\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}(x)\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}(x)\}\subseteq\{x\in X:g_{0,n}\neq g_{1,n}\}\in\mathscr{A}$, and $\mu(A)=0$, which means $\{x\in X:\limsup_{n\to\infty}g_{0,n}(x)\neq\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_{1,n}(x)\}$ is $\mu$-negligible, and so $f_0=f_1$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere.


For This Post
Could someone please help me with my question 2?
Moreover, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check if my attempt for the other four questions are correct!

A simple function by definition has finitely many values. The author says "if $f$ is simple ... attaining values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$", so the finiticity of its values is assumed in the beginning of the sentence :)

@Al.G. Thanks a lot! I keep neglecting the condition that the function is "simple".
